# Show appropriate div on select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a drop-down and need to show hidden div that corresponds to the selected option and do nothing when a blank option is selected:

```
$("#hiddenDiv1").hide();
$("#hiddenDiv2").hide();

$('#mySelector').change(function() {

});
```

```
<select id="mySelector">
    <option>select one option</option>
    <option value="option1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="hiddenDiv1">aaaaa</div>
<div id="hiddenDiv2">bbbbb</div>
```

That's as far as I was able to get on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Emmanuel's answer:

```
var $div1 = $('#hiddenDiv1'),
    $div2 = $('#hiddenDiv2'),
    $both = $div1.add($div2);

$('#mySelector').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.val();

    switch (val)
    {
        case 'option1':
            $div1.show();
            $div2.hide();
            break;

        case 'option2':
            $div1.hide();
            $div2.show();
            break;

        default:
            $both.hide();
    }
});
```

#### Edit

Since there seems to be some desire to turn this into a bit of code golf, here's my reduced-line-count version (no changes to the OP's markup):

```
var $hiddenDivs = $('div[id^=hiddenDiv]').hide();
$('#mySelector').change(function() {
    $hiddenDivs.hide().filter('[id$=' + $(this).val().substring(6) + ']').show();
});
```

[jsfiddle demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/t4aHV/)

Comment: @Matt Ball - Meh. Is this the best you can do?

Comment: It gets the job done. I didn't want to do anything fancy for a jQuery n00b.

Comment: I'd probably start with putting the appropriate `div`'s ID into a `data-*` attribute and go from there.

Comment: you know your code is wrong when it can be done as efficient with 5 times less code.. using a switch for this makes no sense.

Comment: @Jared and @amosrivera, if you're unsatisfied with my answer you are more than welcome to edit it with improvements, or post your own answers. I have not seen either one. As I said before, I was trying to write the code with readability and clarity in mind, not brevity, for someone who is new to jQuery.

Comment: @Matt - Now that's interesting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple.

**Javascript**

```
$('.hiddenDiv').hide();
function showHide(value){
    $('.hiddenDiv:visible').hide();
    $('#div_'+value).show();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelector" onchange="showHide(this.value)">
    <option>select one option</option>
    <option value="option1">option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="div_option1" class="hiddenDiv">aaaaa</a>
<div id="div_option2" class="hiddenDiv">bbbbb</a>
```

---

*Edit*

Okay, so another way to do the js, without the inline event is this:

**Javascript**

```
$('#mySelector').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.hiddenDiv:visible').hide();
    $('#div_'+value).show();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="mySelector">
    <option>select one option</option>
    <option value="option1">option 1
    <option value="option2">option 2
</select>

<div id="div_option1" class="hiddenDiv">aaaaa</a>
<div id="div_option2" class="hiddenDiv">bbbbb</a>
```

Comment: Agreed with @Jared. There is almost never a compelling reason to use inline event handlers, especially when using jQuery.

Comment: That would require the OP to change the markup, and I don't think that's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If your scenario allows you to name the DIV's consist with the option values, then:

**HTML:**

```
<select id="mySelector">
   <option>select one option</option>
   <option value="option1">option 1</option>
   <option value="option2">option 2</option>
</select>

<div id="content_option1">aaaaa</div>
<div id="content_option2">bbbbb</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("div[id^='content']").hide();
$("#mySelector").change(function () {
    $("div[id^='content']").hide();
    $("#content_" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

It's similar to @Emmanuel's solution except without the additional class.

Comment: jQuery supports a number of attribute selector variants. The ^ prefix is for "starts with". See http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ for details.

Comment: I'm not seeing the benefit to doing the approach you have here, adding the `content_` to the id. That should be classed, IMO, since that is what you are indicating when you tag it like that.

Comment: @Jared Fair enough. As a personal preference, I favor solutions that are either overtly or implicitly semantic. In this case one could argue that a class attribute could be just as semantic as an ID prefix. Either solution would be fine IMO.

Comment: Except that's what classes are for and you don't need to do any fancy selecting to get the related elements.